# Why is Rcpp Runtime Different on Windows Vs. Unix

Tags: r, rcpp

I have optimized some R code to use Rcpp for computational efficiency. My code is below. My code is compiled in a package and works on all tested platforms (multiple local windows machines and deployed in a shiny app at shinyapps.io) in the sense that all results are the same irrespective of what machine ran the code. The shinyapps.io uses a Ubuntu linux-based OS, however, and I believe this is something I need to pay attention to.

When I run the pure R version of my code at shinyapps.io, it runs very fast (~30 seconds). When I run the code that uses my Rcpp function, it produces the same result as the pure R version, but runs very slow (~ 3 minutes). When I run these on a local windows desktop, the result is the opposite--my pure R version runs slow but my Rcpp version runs fast and again both versions produce identical results.

I build my package on a windows 10 machine as follows in Rstudio with R 4.2.2:

1. Build new project using Rcpp Armadillo
2. Then, to build the package go to "Build -> Build source package"

This is suggesting I need to do something to compile the code or build the source package differently so the code runs just as quickly on a Linux-based OS as it does on Windows. I am unable to find an FAQ or other comparable post on SO.

Can anyone suggest something I should read or advise on a solution?

```
#include <RcppArmadillo.h>
// [[Rcpp::depends(RcppArmadillo)]]
// [[Rcpp::export]]

arma::vec irt_like(arma::mat X, arma::mat X2, arma::mat pr, arma::vec wts) 
    {
      arma::vec res = exp(X * log(pr.t()) + X2 * log(1-pr.t())) * wts;
      return res;
    }
```

Comment: The bigger picture is that a) the OS matters (for many things but also file access and internal memory management) and b) profiling helps to find bottlement and c) performance tuning can be hard work.  If I had to guess I'd say your shiny app is not likely to benefit from replacing _an already vectorised call into compiled code_ that R makes with one you offer here.

Comment: Thanks, @DirkEddelbuettel. Indeed my pure R version is vectorized and highly efficient. But I was hoping for some cost savings here. I suppose I was naively approaching this from the perspective that R is R no matter what OS is used and perhaps that naivety bit me here and was hopeful that because the conversion to Rcpp worked so well on windows it would have had the same savings on Ubuntu. Just to ask what may be a dumb question, is there some overhead associated with passing objects from R to Rcpp that could be slowing things down?

Comment: The short answer is 'no, not really', the medium answer is 'you can measure that' and the longer answer is of course in the code so 'yes there are nano- to microsecond delays' in function call argument checks (but R does that too so "it depends"). But that is *not likely* the cause of your slowdown.  I can only reiterate that as boring as it sounds, what you want and need now are a good tutorial or two on profiling.  R has decent tools here, they can be of help. Good luck!

Comment: Indeed will spend time on this, @DirkEddelbuettel. Just to put a fine point on this, it’s really cross platform profiling here, right? I’ve profiled pretty extensively within windows (e.g, profvis, microbenchmark, etc). But the real lesson is just because it worked for me well within that environment does not imply those same cost savings would be observed in a different environment, is that the right lesson here?